# Stack accessible by all member functions of a class

Tags: c++, class, stack, member-functions

I want all member functions of a class to have access to the same stack. Each member function will push data to the stack and pop data from the stack.

I am having a hard time declaring the stack. I have a cpp file and a header file it won't let me declare a stack in the header file. Does anyone have an example of how this could be done?

I need to use a stack as a LIFO data structure makes more sense as I only need to access the last item placed on the stack.

I tried declaring it in the header file as a protected member with `stack<int> items;` but get a compile error "stack does not name a type".

Adam

Comment: Is this stack object a (private) member of your class?

Comment: Any example code of how you are trying to do this and what the compiler complains about would be quite helpful.

Comment: @kol No its not a member at all at the moment. I tried declaring it as a protected member in the header file with: stack<int> items; But it doesn't work it gives the compile error "stack not a type"

Comment: Have you added `#include <stack>` at the beginning of your header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass around basic data structures.

Your stack represents something, maybe a stack of `Orders` in a sandwich shop, or a stack of `Pancakes` being rendered in glorious 5D. Create an object of type `Pancakes`, or `Orders` as appropriate, and pass a reference to objects that need to know about it.

```
// pancakes.h
#include <stack>    
class Pancake;

class Pancakes
{
public:
    void addPancake(const Pancake& pancake);
    Pancake& top() const;
    void pop();
private:
    std::stack<Pancake> m_pancakes;
};

// pancakes.cpp
#include "pancakes.h"
#include "pancake.h"

void Pancakes::addPancake(const Pancake& pancake)
{
    m_pancakes.push(pancake);
}

Pancake& Pancakes::top() const
{
    return m_pancakes.top();
}

void Pancakes::pop()
{
    m_pancakes.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's assume you're using a std::stack.

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::stack<int>& myStack_;
public:

    MyClass(std::stack<int>& stack) : myStack_(stack) { };
}; // eo MyClass
```

Just pass a reference to the stack each time you make an instance of `MyClass`.  This also avoids singletons:

```
std::stack<int> globalStack;
MyClass class1(globalStack);
MyClass class2(globalStack);
```

Comment: Think about the use of static in front of std::stack, that tells the Compiler to use the _same_ stack in each instance.

Comment: @EGOrecords, think about that bad use of a static stack as a cheap global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you do a

```
#include <stack>
```

and additionally either do a

```
using namespace std;
```

or a

```
std::stack<int> items;
```

in the header file.

Comment: Suggesting the use of `using namespace std;` in a header file is not good advice!

Comment: I'd say that absolutely depends. In any case it should solve the OP's problem.